# How can I share Tampermonkey scripts between versions of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, tampermonkey

I use the normal version of Chrome as well as Canary (on both Windows and OS X).  It's kind of a pain that my TamperMonkey scripts are only available in one or the other.  Trying to maintain both, and synchronize changes I made in one to the other, is a ridiculous pain.

I understand that [TamperMonkey stores its scripts in a SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11850460/241142).  Is there a way to share this between browser versions?

Comment: Have you tried using a third party tool to simply synchronise the folder contents?

Comment: There scripts are not stored in a folder.  They're stored in a SQLite database.  One solution might be to use a tool to synchronize SQLite dbs, but that can be [costly](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/datasync/purchase/).  I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: The current beta version of Tampermonkey lists "easily sync/install your scripts from a single document" as a feature. Have you tried it out?

Comment: Nope... I'll see if I can upgrade to that version.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see a way to [use beta versions of extensions](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+beta+version+of+chrome+extension&oq=use+beta+version+of+chrome+extension&aqs=chrome.0.57j65l3j60l2.5030&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) either on google or [in the Chrome UI](chrome://extensions/)

Comment: It has it's own extension page: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey-beta/gcalenpjmijncebpfijmoaglllgpjagf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use your Google account to sync scripts. (This is only in Beta yet)

**Step1:** Log into your Google account in the Google Chrome browser
[image]

**Step2:** Go into Tampermonkey Dashboard, then into Settings and change the "Config mode" to "Advanced".
[image]

**Step3:** Enable "Tesla" and choose "Chrome Sync"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As on v4.8.41, 
Go into Tampermonkey Dashboard, then into Settings and change the "Config mode" to "Beginner" or "Advanced".

- Go to Script Sync (6th option)
- Tick Enable Script Sync
- Choose Google Drive as Type
- Click Sync

Answer (score 1):

Synchronize scripts that are downloadable from a Webserver.
Just set the config mode to beginner or advanced, enable TESLA.
Set the mode to chrome sync and login with chrome to your Google account.