# Is it possible to synchronize userscripts between Google Chrome installations?

Tags: google-chrome, userscripts

I've noticed that userscripts aren't automatically synchronized like (regular) extensions in Google Chrome.

Is there any way to ensure that userscripts are synchronized between Chrome installations?

Comment: It appears that it's possible to create a Chrome extension from a Greasemonkey script: http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/how-to-create-a-google-chrome-extension-from/

Comment: That blog post is obsolete.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome/5259212#5259212) for more up to date information.  Also, Chrome userscripts are auto-converted to extensions anyway.

Comment: @BrockAdams In that case, is there any way to synchronize a userscript's locally stored data between Chrome installations?

Comment: @BrockAdams I want to find some way to synchronize the local storage for Chrome userscripts. I wonder if it's possible to use `chrome.storage` in userscripts: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Comment: @BrockAdams Correction, the `chrome.storage` feature is also available in Content scripts if the `storage` permission is specified in the manifest file.

Comment: @RobW, good to know.  According to the docs, the storage permission must be set irregardless, for storage to work.

Comment: (replacing earlier comments) I *think* that to sync extensions, they must be uploaded to Google's web store. For sharing data, `chrome.storage` just might work.  If not, setting up a server, that your scripts can AJAX data to and from, would work.

Comment: It seems that only extensions hosted on Chrome Web Store will be automatically synced.

Comment: You might install Tampermonkey, which is synched, and see if scripts installed with it are synched.  They might be.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is [already possible to synchronize userscripts](http://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=414) using the Tampermonkey extension for Google Chrome. To synchronize userscripts, go to the "settings" tab of Tampermonkey. Set "config mode" to "beginner" or "advanced", and then enable "Chrome Sync" under "TESLA".

Comment: I enabled that option on both of my Chrome installations but it did not sync my script.

Comment: Tampermonkey will only sync external scripts

Comment: A simple way to store your userscripts externaly and keep them in sync is to store them in Dropbox and then share them. Once Dropbox gave you the share URL, just replace the parameter `?dl=0`by `?dl=1` which will serve the file instead of showing it. Then, in your userscript header, just add `@downloadURL https://www.dropbox.com/s/......./usercript_example.js?dl=1`. Don't forget to increment the `@version` so that TamperMonkey will detect the update.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/506221/how-can-i-share-tampermonkey-scripts-between-versions-of-chrome/1453402#1453402