# How can I get Tampermonkey's Chrome Sync to actually sync?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, tampermonkey

Firstly, the Tampermonkey sync setup is described [here](https://superuser.com/a/656531/170163).

The above-described process is not working for me, however. I've written a few scripts on one machine, where Chrome Sync is enabled, and have enabled the same sync functionality on a couple of other machines, neither of which are picking up the scripts. On all of the machines, Chrome is logged into my Google account.

I wondered if there might be some kind of delay, but everything has been setup for nearly 24 hrs at this point, so I don't believe that is an issue.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that Chrome Sync requires there to be an `@downloadURL` or `@updateURL` tag set where the service can retrieve the script information. The only data actually synced via the Chrome Sync service is the URL to the script, not the script itself.

Since all my scripts were made by myself, this doesn't work. There does not appear to be a working solution for syncing personal scripts conveniently at this time.

Chrome Sync details found here: http://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=312

Comment: Unless there is some kind of secret in the scripts, you can just upload them to github or something to make the url sync work.